# Emitting events from components to router-view - bad code smell

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I’m experimenting with Vue Router and I’ve got a bad smell coming out. Need to check with the community to see if I’m doing things right.

Prior to Vue Router I had a component as a parent receiving an event from its child and updating my main app data property:

`<number-pad v-on:button-click="updateTotal($event)"></number-pad>`

Don’t worry about the details but it was working.

When I move this into Vue Router it’s going to look something like this now...

```
const pageOne = {
    name: "page-one",
    template: `
    <div>
        <number-pad v-on:button-click="updateTotal($event)"></number-pad>
    </div>  `
};
```

...with the following in my HTML:

```
<router-view></router-view>
```

There’s a lot more I’m leaving out but you get the gist.

Anyway, this will render just fine and update the internals of the component, of course, but the directive isn’t going to communicate with the main data property any more unless I adjust some code to emit the data up one more level to the `<router-view>` component:

```
<router-view v-on:button-click="updateTotal($event)"></router-view>
```

It will now work (along with other code tweaks I'm not writing out for the sake of brevity).

In other words, when it comes to component relationships I went from a parent -> child relationship before Vue Router to a grandparent -> parent -> child relationship after.

Do I seriously have to duplicate all my bindings and directives to this new `<router-view>` grandparent in order to communicate to the main data property?

This smells very bad to me and is also a huge pain in the a**.

What can I do to make this situation better? Is the answer: Vuex! Or is the answer: no, you dope, you overlooked something simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Vuex is one of the answers, but you can also define an event bus, i.e:

**/src/event-bus.js**

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()
```

Import it in a component that's emitting:

```
import EventBus from '@/event-bus'
```

You would emit an event like this:

```
EventBus.$emit('button-click', payload)
```

Now import EventBus in a component that's receiving the event, and add a listener in your mounted hook:

```
mounted() {
  EventBus.$on('button-click', payload => {
    // handle event
  })
}
```

This works app-wide.

Comment: For this to work for me I had to use `export default` i.e. `const EventBus = new Vue()

export default EventBus`

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do this :

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    ...
    <router-view @child-event="handleChildEvent" />
    ...
  </div>
</template>
```

You can learn more [here](https://www.danvega.dev/blog/2019/06/05/triggering-events-router-vue/).